# How to use SetDisplayConfig

Tags: winapi

I am trying to use SetDisplayConfig in a c++ project in order to manage the dysplays. I use windows 7 as OS and Visual Studio 2008 as editor. I include the header Winuser.h as suggested but when I try to compile the error 'SetDisplayConfig': identifier not found occurs. Any idea about the reason?

Thanks,
Giorgio

Comment: The documentation for [SetDisplayConfig](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569533.aspx) mandates that you include **Windows.h**.

Comment: @IInspectable That's right, but I guess problem is likely that the version defines are not setup for Win7 and later

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN documentation for the Windows API usually names both the header file, that declares an identifier, as well as the header file you should include. [SetDisplayConfig](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569533.aspx) is no different in that respect:

> **Header** Winuser.h (include Windows.h)

To use `SetDisplayConfig` you need to include *Windows.h*.

Since this API is available in Windows 7 and later versions, you also have to set the `_WIN32_WINNT` preprocessor symbol, prior to including *Windows.h*:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
```

Alternatively, you can define the preprocessor symbol inside the IDE, to have it passed to the compiler on the command line. Doing it this way ensures, that the symbol is defined prior to any includes. Additional information is available at [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx).